# What was Dease's main angst?

Tags: plot-explanation, velvet-buzzsaw

In the movie *Velvet Buzzsaw*, we are shown that Dease's paintings have the power to kill people. But not all of the characters are killed. What is the reason someone is marked for death?

(I've already gone through an explanation that talks about "Greed". Dease doesn't seem to be someone who's trying to heal the world and make it a better place free of "greedy" people or ones who "sin")

In short, Dease's vengeance seems to be focused on a particular trait a character exhibits, and only those characters die. What is that trait?

Comment: Do you mean, all of the characters who own a dease painting? I don’t recall any of them who were introduced not dying...?

Comment: merely owning it is not what causes the death. I believe if Piers had purchased the painting he wouldn't have died. Which also brings be to that last scene, are those people going to die because they're selling it?

Comment: Merely owning them may certainly be the death, all of those who do own a dease on screen died. Piers didnt purchase a painting, and the implication i took at the end of the film was much like the grudge, the devil is out of the box and those who purchase will meet an untimely end...though, i may have forgotten an on screen purchaser who didnt die...is that possible?

Comment: when he was still alive, he spent a good part of his life in the orphanage and then was in the military service. After that he kills his father. And till that point he's never painted. The he's taken to that hospital for many years. His whole painting stint starts after that, but his killing started much before. His angst seems more generic than people owning his art. They needed to display some trait and one off the answers talks about greed. But is it really just greed?

Answer (score 1):

From [the french wikipedia page of the movie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velvet_Buzzsaw):

> all those who have allowed their greed to stand in the way of art

Comment: thanks for the answer, stand in the way of art - sure. But Dease is was not tormented in his life as part of the art world. He has no reason to specifically take it out on the art vertical right?